# How can I substitute placeholders in a txt file template using data from a csv?

Tags: python, csv

I have a project that I've been working on for my intro computer science class and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong in my current implementation. I'm supposed to read data from a CSV, which includes data of customers of a fictional travel company. I'm then supposed to open a .txt file template and replace the placeholders (in the format [[placeholder]]) with the data on the CSV, then save a new txt file for each customer with the proper replacement. As if I am sending a new email to each customer in the CSV.

I was able to load the CSV and put the data in the CSV into an array, while the headers of the CSV (which are identical to the placeholders, just not in double brackets) are in a list:

```
file_obj = open(PATH_SAVE_DIR + csv_filename, newline='')
reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj)
headers = reader.fieldnames  # list of headers

file_obj.close()

customerdata = []
with open(PATH_SAVE_DIR + csv_filename, 'r') as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    row = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        customerdata.append(row)
```

This gives me the following array, with the data from the CSV:

```
[['James', 'Butt', '6649 N Blue Gum St', 'New Orleans', 'Orleans', 'LA', '70116', '504-621-8927', 'jbutt@gmail.com', 'gold'], ['Josephine', 'Darakjy', '4 B Blue Ridge Blvd', 'Brighton', 'Livingston', 'MI', '48116', '810-292-9388', 'josephine_darakjy@darakjy.org', 'silver'], ['Art', 'Venere', '8 W Cerritos Ave #54', 'Bridgeport', 'Gloucester', 'NJ', '8014', '856-636-8749', 'art@venere.org', 'bronze']]
```

The part where I'm having difficulty understanding what is happening is when trying to replace the data of the txt file with the customer's data. My current code is able to replace the data in the file, but it only does it with the first set of data, and never seems to counts up in the array and work with the next customer's data:

```
file_obj = open(PATH_SAVE_DIR + EMAIL_TEMPLATE, 'r')
file_input = file_obj.read()

count = 0
for customer in range(len(customerdata)):
    customernumber = str(customer + 1)
    while count < len(customerdata):
        for word in headers:
            if word in file_input:
                index = headers.index(word)
                file_input = file_input.replace("[[" + word + "]]",
                                                customerdata[count][index])
        count += 1
    file_output = open(PATH_SAVE_DIR + EMAIL + customernumber + ".txt", 'w')
    file_output.write(file_input)
    file_output.close()


file_obj.close()
```

So it is able to successfully create email1.txt, email2.txt and email3.txt, but all three of the files are identical and only include the replaced data of the first customer. I tried putting `print (count)` in different spots around my `for word in headers` loop, and it seems like it only runs that specific for loop a single time with the first customer, then doesn't attempt it again with the count going up (for the next customer in the array). How can I repeat this loop to do it for each customer?

I suppose the string replacement can be done with regular expression substitution as well, but we haven't been taught regular expressions yet, so I'm still a bit unclear as to how I would implement it using those.

**Edit:** I was able to come up with a working code. Still have to edit the formatting some, but at least it's now doing what I want it to do.

```
file_obj = open(PATH_SAVE_DIR + EMAIL_TEMPLATE, 'r')
file_input = file_obj.read()
file_obj.close()
for customer in range(len(customerdata)):
    customernumber = str(customer + 1)
    for word in headers:
        if word in file_input:
            index = headers.index(word)
            replaced = file_input.replace("[[" + word + "]]",
                                          customerdata[customer][index])
            file_input = replaced
        with open(PATH_SAVE_DIR + EMAIL + customernumber + ".txt", 'w') \
        as file_output:
            file_output.write(replaced)
    with open(PATH_SAVE_DIR + EMAIL_TEMPLATE, 'r') as file_obj:
        file_input = file_obj.read()
```

Comment: if you do want to learn how to implement it with regular expressions, you can use this  https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: The way I would do something like this is read it in one line at a time. Then split the line on each space. Then iterate through the list that you created when you split the line and replace any "[placeholder]" string in that list with the appropriate information. Then merge the list back into a string, and write it to the file.

Although maybe regex would be easier... lol

Comment: This might not be directly related to your issue but it will definitely help your code readability if you start iterating directly over lists. Instead of `for i in range(len(customers)): customer = customers[i]...`, you can just write `for customer in customers:` This results in a lot less `count`, `index`, etc. type variables for python programmers to keep track of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have two loop structures where you only want one. The first one is for customer in range(len(customerdata)):, and the second one is while count < len(customerdata):. So basically you're looping over all the customers twice. The file-write statement is embedded in one loop but not in the other, so your script is reading data from customers 0, 1, 2, and writing data[2] to the file, reading 0, 1, 2, and writing data[2] to the file... Does that help?

Edit: The other issue is that you're overwriting your template with your messages, so it stops functioning as a template after the first overwrite.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that I had to read from the template again, so I was able to properly write things into the new files by just opening and reading from the template file again. Will edit my original post with what I changed.

Comment: You don't need to refresh from the file. I'd recommend just keeping the template in a list, and then in each loop, `email = template.replace(blah, blah)` and write "email" to the outfile.